# could multiple live WiFi profiles coexist on ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, 13.04

At work there are couple wifi available for different purpose. My laptop can connect to any one of them if only one wifi was configured on Ubuntu, i.e. only one wifi profile is valid at the time. However, if more than one were configured, Ubuntu could not connect to any one of them.

dmesg reported "deauthenticating from 04:c5:a4:09:51:3d by local choice (reason=3)"
or "deauthenticating from 04:c5:a4:09:51:3d by local choice (reason=2)"

Laptop:

- HP folio 9470m
- Ubuntu 13.04 Kylin

  ```
  uname -a
  Linux HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

These wifi could be switched on Windows 7 without any issue. It would be great if somebody could find out what is the problem and how to fix it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

List of reason codes([ref](http://forums.wi-fiplanet.com/showthread.php?6536-deauthentication-reason-code)):

```
0...noReasonCode...Normal operation.
1...unspecifiedReason...Client associated but no longer authorized.
2...previousAuthNotValid...Client associated but not authorized.
3...deauthenticationLeaving...The access point went offline, deauthenticating the client.
4...disassociationDueToInactivity...Client session timeout exceeded.
5...disassociationAPBusy...The access point is busy, performing load balancing, for example.
6...class2FrameFromNonAuthStation...Client attempted to transfer data before it was authenticated.
7...class2FrameFromNonAssStation...Client attempted to transfer data before it was associated.
8...disassociationStaHasLeft...Operating System moved the client to another access point using non-aggressive load balancing.
9...staReqAssociationWithoutAuth...Client not authorized yet, still attempting to associate with an access point.
99...missingReasonCode...Client momentarily in an unknown state.
```

Might be [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpasupplicant/+bug/872578) "Won't fix" bug.  I get from that report that NetworkManager is having trouble determining which one is "best".

Disclaimer - I use wicd, and it seems to work in your scenario.